# Stop following and allow scrolling

Tags: 18.04, less

`less +F` can be used to "tail" follow an input stream.  I can't find a way to disable this mode and resume manual scrolling.

From man:less...

> F
>
> Scroll forward, and keep trying to read when the end of file is
>   reached.    Normally this command would be used when already at
>   the end of the file. It is a way to monitor the tail of a file
>   which is growing while it is being viewed. (The behavior is
>   similar to the "tail -f" command.)
>
> ESC-F
>
> Like F, but as soon as a line is found which matches the last
>   search pattern, the terminal bell is rung and forward scrolling
>   stops.

It seems like `ESC-F` may be the answer, but I'm not familiar with that key-sequence and don't seem to be able to make it work.

Comment: Also in `man less`: `ESC stands for the ESCAPE key; for example ESC-v means the two character sequence "ESCAPE", then "v".`

Comment: @wjandrea -- Thanks.  Yeah, it seems pretty obvious -- it just doesn't work for me in this context, so I though maybe I was missing something.

Comment: I'm having *slightly* more luck with [`most`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_(Unix)).  In that case it's a bit more obvious that the problem is probably that these programs are single-threaded and use blocking reads to tail the input stream -- so they become unresponsive to keyboard input when waiting for new input lines.

Comment: Best solution so far: Forget about using a specific "pager" utility -- just run `tail` (or whatever) in a modern GUI terminal.  That will allow you to scroll.  You can change the zoom to reduce wrapping (or use [`cut`](https://superuser.com/q/58811/114579)).  The 18.04 version of `mate-terminal` will reflow text when the window is resized.

Answer (score 0):

While tailing a file, `less` says at the bottom, `Waiting for data... (interrupt to abort)`. So just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, which sends the interrupt signal (SIGINT).

Comment: Hmm, I'm not seeing that message.  If I `Ctrl-C`, `less` terminates altogether and I'm returned to the shell.

Comment: @nobar Are you running `less +F`?

Comment: Yes.  I've done it that way, and also without `+F` -- but then typing `Shift`+`F` to enter  tail mode.  The result is the same either way.